# Is it possible to convert a webapp coded using angular 1 to PWA(Progressive Web App)?

Tags: angularjs, progressive-web-apps

I have a webapp devoloped using angular 1. I have to convert it to progressive web app is this possible, I had looked into many tutorials in youtube but all of them uses angular 2 and above. Does angular 1 supports this PWA features? Please help...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's nothing framework-specific about PWAs - your site just has to meet a [certain set of criteria](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/checklist):

- Everything is served over HTTPS
- The design must be responsive
- Your app must be available offline (i.e. it needs a [Service Worker](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/))
- You need to provide a [manifest file](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest) containing metadata about your application
- Your app must work in all modern browsers
- Page transitions shouldn't block the app (i.e. you need to show loading screens/spinners if things are taking a while to load)
- Each page in the app needs a unique URL

All of that is achievable with Angular 1 - it'll probably be *easier* with a modern framework, but there's nothing stopping you sticking with what you've got, for now at least.

Addy Osmani (who I believe works at Google and is pretty heavily involved with the PWA spec) has [a good example of an Angular 1 PWA on his GitHub](https://github.com/addyosmani/angular1-dribbble-pwa).

Comment: My code was successful, I had added serviceworker.js and manifest, I forgot to clear the caches in my mobile. That was the problem and not with the code. Now its working fine. @JoeClay I had up voted your answer.

Comment: @AntonyJoslin: Glad I could help :) If this answered your question, I'd appreciate it if you'd mark it as answered (click the tick under the votes).

Comment: @AntonyJoslin im trying the same, how did u got it? can u share the tutorial you followed? thanks!

Comment: @AlbertoAcuña Follow this link : https://medium.com/@ahsan.ayaz/creating-progressive-web-apps-with-angular-part-1-8f752b866f29
OR
https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-progressive-web-apps-with-angular

Comment: @JoeClay angular1 pwa can send notifications? thanks dude

Comment: @AlbertoAcuña: There's nothing stopping you using the [Notifications and Push APIs](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-push-notifications) (or any other web API) in an Angular 1.x application, as long as the end user's browser supports it. It's all just JavaScript, at the end of the day.

Comment: @JoeClay can u share me some tutorial pls, thanku so much!

Comment: @JoeClay "it'll probably be easier with a modern framework",   Like which one ?

Answer (score 2):

My code was successful, I had added serviceworker.js and manifest, I forgot to clear the caches in my mobile. That was the problem and not with the code. Now its working fine. Clear the caches in test devices and it to homescreen once again and it will work.